# Secure to verify code signature like this?

Tags: powershell, validation, digital-signature, code-signing

I like to verify a downloaded Windows executable by verifying the signature. I read the signature with a Powershell command like this:

`Get-AuthenticodeSignature .\SomeFile.exe | Format-List -property Status, SignerCertificate`

By this I get a validation result (Valid or Invalid) and the Subject of the used certificate. Is it secure to check the validation result and the CN name of the subject with some RegEx to make sure that the signature is valid and originated by me?

I don't like to use the public key as it is a code signing certificate which may change in the future and I would have to compile it in months before. I think this is not practicable.

So, in other words, is it easy for an attacker to create a fake signature which contains *CN=myCompany* and being recognized as valid on my customers PC?

Comment: If a hacker can coerce your customer to trust a self-signed cert, then yes, it's easy for a hacker to create a valid self-signed cert that contains "CN=myCompany".  Similarly, if a hacker obtained your private key, they could sign SomeFile.exe using your "CN=myCompany" cert.  A hacker can also setup a Get-AuthenticodeSignature function in your customer's PowerShell profile to override the default cmdlet, and return "Valid" and "CN=myCompany".  Hackers can also swap-out files after validation.  Most of these scenarios are probably highly unlikely, but are still possible under right conditions.

Comment: Thanks, @leeharvey1. Of course, if a hacker is already on the target system, everything is possible and he does not need my download to infiltrate the system. Lets assume the target is not yet hacked. But I wonder if hackers are able to easily create a trusted fake signature that bypasses my security check. My software downloads an update and I want to verify like described before execution. The question is, is that secure?

Comment: Your check is fine, and probably more than most software vendors perform -- especially if you control the download, as well.  However, for better security, I'd check the cert thumbprint, rather than the Subject's common name.  BTW, I've seen others report strange results from Get-AuthenticodeSignature; which may be dependent upon installed certs, supported signature hash algorithms, installed Windows security updates, as well as .NET Framework versions.  Keep this in mind if your check fails or reports misleading results on some customer systems.

Comment: @leeharvey1 I cant use the certificate thumbprint because at some future moment I have to create a new code signing certificate. And I doubt the thumbprint will stay exactly the same. Imagine I'm not able to reproduce the same thumbprint and all my updates from previous versions fail updating (not knowing the new thumbprint yet). That would be a nightmare. This is the reason I focus on validity and the CN attribute only.